# JSON returning with "\" (Lambda)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, http-get, aws-lambda, openweathermap

I am using AWS Lambda to get JSON from the open weather api and return it.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a";
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        // Continuously update stream with data
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            context.succeed(body);
        });
        res.on('error', function(e) {
            context.fail("Got error: " + e.message);
        });
    });
}
```

It works and returns the JSON, but it is adding backslashes before every **"** like so:

```
"{\"coord\":{\"lon\":145.77,\"lat\":-16.92},\"weather\":[{\"id\":803,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"broken clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"}],\"base\":\"cmc stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":303.15,\"pressure\":1008,\"humidity\":74,\"temp_min\":303.15,\"temp_max\":303.15},\"wind\":{\"speed\":3.1,\"deg\":320},\"clouds\":{\"all\":75},\"dt\":1458518400,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":8166,\"message\":0.0025,\"country\":\"AU\",\"sunrise\":1458505258,\"sunset\":1458548812},\"id\":2172797,\"name\":\"Cairns\",\"cod\":200}"
```

This is stopping my over service using (SwiftJSON) detecting this as valid JSON.

Can anyone tell me how to make the API information come out as correctly formatted JSON?

I tried `.replace` like so:

```
 res.on('end', function() {

        result = body.replace('\\', '');
        context.succeed(result);
    });
```

It did not change anything. Still had the same output.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're posting it as a string.

Try context.succeed(JSON.parse(result))

From the docs

The result provided must be JSON.stringify compatible. If AWS Lambda fails to stringify or encounters another error, an unhandled exception is thrown, with the X-Amz-Function-Error response header set to Unhandled.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

So essentially it's taking your json string as a string and calling JSON.stringify on it...thus escaping all the quotes as you're seeing. Pass the parsed JSON object to succeed and it should not have this issue

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In case of Java, just return a JSONObject. Looks like when returning string it is trying to do some transformation and ends up escaping all the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If using Java, the response can be a user defined object as below

```
class Handler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, CustomObject> {
    public CustomObject handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
        return new CustomObject();
    }
}
```

Sample code can be found [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/8c08f832a4f2df60f5338cb68b1635fb42cc0bcd/sample-apps/java-basic/src/main/java/example/HandlerWeatherData.java).

Answer (score -1):

Do this on your result: response.json()

Comment: this does not seem to answer the question. Please can you explain in more detail how this is a solution to this question.

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
    res.on('end', function() {
 context.succeed(body.replace(/\\/g, '') );
```

To replace \ with nothing..

Comment: Where do i use this?

Comment: I updated the answer, if its not working try json.parse(body)

Comment: @JamesG I updated the code again,, replace this code with this res.on('end', function() { context.succeed(body);